# mysql show select output replacing characters

Tags: mysql

I have some table with email filed, i want to get group of emails using group concat. no issue  there
it give out put like  following

```
 test@domain.com,test2@domain.com ,test3@domain.com  ,test4@domain.com
```

but i want to get result as following

```
 test_domain.com,test2_domain.com ,test3_domain.com
```

I know this can be done using simple PHP explode  but i want to know there is any way
to do that only using MYSQL..............

Comment: So your goal is to replace `@` with `_` in your MySQL query output? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the mysql replace string function around your group_concat:

```
 Select ...,replace(group_concat(...), '@','_'),...
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace